# choice between 'unique' and 'exclusive' here

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

This is from [a webpage](https://simpleflying.com/does-sam-chui-get-paid-to-fly/) :

> Some say that, because Sam is so well known, he gets treated better on
> his flights. While that may be true, not everything he experiences is
> **unique** to him. He said,
>
> “If you were to go on the same plane, the seats are the same, the
> meals are the same, the people around are the same, the galleys the
> same, the cockpit the same…

I looked up '**unique**' in the Merriam-Webster dictionary and [definition 2b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique) makes it seem as if the sentence means that not everything he experiences is a distinctive characteristic of him.

So I think '*exclusive*' which means '[limited to possession, control, or use by a single individual or group](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusive)' is more appropriate than 'unique' here.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Collins dictionary at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unique states "if something is unique to a place or situation, it only exists in that place or situation". I think this statement is more helpful than the M-W definition in your context.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much. You mean 'unique' is appropriate in that context. Right?

Comment: Either word could work in this sentence.

Comment: @Peter I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Peter Care to make an answer of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "unique" does not only apply to distinct *characteristics*, as OP's linked Merriam-Webster dictionary entry (meaning 2b) appears to suggest. An alternative definition at [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unique) is

> if something is unique to a place or situation, it only exists in that place or situation.

I find this statement more helpful for the given context.

Either "unique" or "exclusive" could be appropriate. Especially when the sentence is negative ("not unique" or "not exclusive") the meanings are similar but not identical. "Not unique" means that Sam is not the only person to have the particular experience. "Not exclusive" means that the experience is not reserved for Sam; others were able to have the same experience even if none actually did.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.